# How can I fixed this jagged border which I get when I apply a CSS border to a toggle switch?

Tags: html, css

I have this toggle switch which I want to bring into my site.

https://jsfiddle.net/njxfnfoa/

```
<div class="switch-container">
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

And the CSS is long, so I'll just keep that in the JSFiddle.

However as you can see it looks quite jagged. The PDF design I'm working to looks like this.

[image: toggle switch]

How can I better replicate this smooth border?

Comment: Depends on the screen/computer your on, Im on a macbook pro and it looks super smooth.

Comment: Doesn't look as bad with a grey border - https://jsfiddle.net/njxfnfoa/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `border: 1px solid rgba(211,211,211, .8);` so you have control over the **Border Opacity** (`0.8` here)

```css
.switch-container{
    position:relative;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    display: none;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border: 1px solid rgba(211,211,211, .8);
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #73c82b;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: white;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(31px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(31px);
    transform: translateX(31px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <div class="slider round"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I'll accept the answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fine tune the css in

```
.slider:before
```

a little bit: [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njxfnfoa/2/)